# Using Jest to test a Link from react-router v4

Tags: react-router, jestjs, react-router-v4

I'm using `jest` to test a component with a `<Link>` from react-router v4.

I get a warning that `<Link />` requires the context from a react-router `<Router />` component.

How can I mock or provide a router context in my test? (Basically how do I resolve this warning?)

**Link.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

test('Link matches snapshot', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Link to="#" />
  );

  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**The warning when the test is run:**

```
Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked 
as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can wrap your component in the test with the StaticRouter to get the router context into your component:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router'

test('Link matches snapshot', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(
    <StaticRouter location="someLocation" context={context}>
      <Link to="#" />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Have a look at the react router [docs about testing](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing)

Comment: The biggest problem is: `componet` refers to `StaticRouter`,so you can't get the component's instance which to be tested.you can't access its props & state such like these.

Comment: You may need to add `const context = {};` above `const component = ...`

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue and using `StaticRouter` would still require the `context` which needed more configuration to have it available in my test, so I ended up using the `MemoryRouter` which worked very well and without any issues.

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// SampleComponent imports Link internally
import SampleComponent from '../SampleComponent';

describe('SampleComponent', () => {
  test('should render', () => {
    const component = renderer
      .create(
        <MemoryRouter>
          <SampleComponent />
        </MemoryRouter>
      )
      .toJSON();

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Mahdi worked for me! In 2023 if you want to test a component that includes `<Link>` or `<NavLink>`, we just need to wrap it with the `<MemoryRouter>` in the test file:

```
// App.test.js

import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent";
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom"; // <-- Import MemoryRouter

test("My test description", () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter> // <-- Wrap!
      <MyComponent />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

my test like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import DataBaseAccout from '../database-account/database-account.component'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { expect } from 'chai'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from '../../../reducer/reducer'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router'

let store = createStore(reducers)

describe('mount database-account', () => {
  let wrapper
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      < MemoryRouter >
        <DataBaseAccout store={store} />
      </MemoryRouter >
    )
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount()
    wrapper = null
  })
})
```

but I don't konw why MemoryRouter can solve this。

Comment: There is a problem,wrapper refers to `MemoryRouter` component, that means you   
 can't operate `DataBaseAccout` component,for  example `wrapper.props()` and `wrapper.state()` will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Above solutions have a common default defact:

**Can't access your component's instance!** Because the `MemoryRouter` or `StaticRouter` component wrapped your component.

So the best to solve this problem is mock a router context, code as follows:

```
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  test('test component with react router', () => {
    // mock react-router context to avoid violation error
    const context = {
      childContextTypes: {
        router: () => void 0,
      },
      context: {
        router: {
          history: createMemoryHistory(),
          route: {
            location: {
              hash: '',
              pathname: '',
              search: '',
              state: '',
            },
            match: { params: {}, isExact: false, path: '', url: '' },
          }
        }
      }
    };
    // mount component with router context and get component's instance
    const wrapper = mount(<YourComponent/>, context);
    // access your component as you wish
    console.log(wrapper.props(), wrapper.state())
  });
  beforeAll(() => {
    configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
  });
});
```

Comment: what does `createMemoryHistory` do?