# Testing components that contain react router Link with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am using enzyme. I need to test a component that has react router Link as a child. I need the following

- mount the component using mount() of enzyme since I need to test the whole component tree
- test behaviours of component when it properties change.

I cannot wrap my component with StaticRouter or MemoryRouter since enzyme only allows setProps() at root level.

My current solution is to stub the Link render method with sinon. Here is a short example.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import sinon from 'sinon';

// ....
// ....

describe('test',() => {
   before(() => {
      sinon.stub(Link.prototype, 'render').callsFake(function reactRouterLinkRender() {
           const {innerRef, replace, to } = this.props;
           const _props = {href: to, ref: innerRef, replace, onClick: this.handleClick};
           return (<a {..._props}>this.props.children</a>);
       });

    });
});
```

Is there a better way to avoid the error "*Invariant Violation: You should not use Link outside a Router*"?

Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer.It may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52533139/5465023

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps anyone but for my case I managed to get around by shallow rendering the top level component and then using dive() to get to the parts I required.

```
loginPage = shallow(<LoginPage />);
```

....

```
loginPage.find(LoginForm).dive().find({name:"user"}).simulate("change", userEventMock);
```